# Hololens 2 Unity WebCamTexture render low framerate

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, frame-rate, hololens, mrtk

I'm rendering the WebCamTexture onto a raw image in Unity, then deploy it to the Hololens 2 to display the internal video camera image. It works but the application tanks to about 15-20 fps. Nothing else is in the scene. If I disable the texture, it runs with 60 fps.

Using Unity version 2020.3.27f1 and MRTK2

Here's the class I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayMovieTextureOnUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture tex;

    public RawImage rawimage;

    void Awake()
    {
        WebCamDevice device = WebCamTexture.devices[0];
        tex = new WebCamTexture(device.name);
        rawimage.texture = tex;

        tex.Play();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

What I've tried so far:

- Use a different Unity version
- Change texture scale
- Change WebCamTexture.requestedFPS, height and width

Comment: I reproduced your issue using your code on Unity2020.3.33f1. But I solved it by setting Height, Width and FPS for WebCamTexture. What versions of Unity did you test on? What are the values you set for WebCamTexture.requestHeight, Width, FPS?

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT The other Unity version I tested was 2020.3.42f1 with the same result. For requestedFPS, height and width I chose FPS: 30, 1280x720 and also 1920x1080. What settings did you use if I may ask?

Comment: Update: Setting the camera to FPS: 30, 1280x720 seems to do the trick. I may not have updated the build correctly before. However, 1920x1080 resolution seems to be too much as it will drop the framerate again.